Is there a resource type authorization check enabled out-of-the-box for fhir-server?
I am wanting to use FHIR Server with Okta. I have successfully integrated Okta (checks tokens on the [Authorize] attribute and can generate a new bearer via the API). However, now I have the below use case:
I have a client that I want to give access to the API that can ONLY Write to Task and DocumentReference resources. I see that inside of the roles.json we can specify various roles and assign them to our user's SCPs, however the one thing I don't see is resource type specific role checks. For example, I don't want them to be able to access the read/write/etc of any other resource types.
When looking in the RoleBasedFhirAuthorizationService I see there is something called SMART access, after doing some digging I found this documentation on it: https://hl7.org/fhir/smart-app-launch/1.0.0/.
I have bits and clues on how this works, but mostly I need help with:
Is there a resource type auth flow available in FHIR server out of the box?
-> If yes, what roles would I need to assign my Okta user in my case? Would there be any other code changes required to configure this?
-> If no, are there any guides or steps I should take to manually add this kind of auth flow?
I have tried looking at the roles.json file but I don't see anything specific to a resource type access.

Which FHIR server?

@GrahameGrieve https://github.com/microsoft/fhir-server the Azure Fhir Server

I ended up contacting the developers at microsoft that run the fhir-server and they gave the following response(s):
"FHIR service offers integration with third party IDP with SMART roles. You are right in understanding the access control in FHIR service is assigned with RBAC roles and scope restrictions is done with help of SMART."
However, it is also important to note:
"I did also want to directly answer your question about read-only scopes support in our Azure FHIR service, which is exactly as you described, we do not currently have write scope support.  If you wanted to try write support you can deploy our open source code which does allow for write scropes, and if you needed to extend it, might be easier: microsoft/fhir-server: A service that implements the FHIR standard (github.com)"
So in this situation, if one needs to provide resource-level and action-level scoping it would have to be an extension of the fhir-server functionality.

Upvote for following up with what you found from M$.    But in my experience the "Roles-based" has tension with the fine-scalpel approach that you are looking for.  But my experience is limited.  Good to see the M$ response lines up with what I (and you I think) have experienced.
